# Added an Autolayout to the UITableViewCell, but I see an unknown phenomenon

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have added an Autolayout to the items in the UITableViewCell, but I have an unknown error.

All items added with AutoLayout will be aligned to the top left corner.

If I add Auto Layout to General Label :[image]

After Build Result: General label moves to the top left corner
[image]

This is true for other items as well.

If I add Auto Layout to General, Total, Final Label :
[image]

There is no code associated with Constraint.
UITableviewCell also has no code.

In View Controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProcDetailMoreCell", for: indexPath) as! ProcDetailMoreCell

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(175)
}
```

I don`t know why this is happening. Please help me see why these results.

Comment: When this happens, switch to Xcode and open the View Debugger. Are there any exclamation marks? These would tell you what problems there are at runtime with your constraints.

Comment: There are no exclamation points. Everything should work perfectly, but I do not know why.

Comment: add general label constraint same as $9999

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two contradictory things. On the one hand you are dictating the height of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(175)
}
```

On the other hand, you have constraints between the General label and the top *and* the bottom. This means that if the height you give (175) is different from the height that you designed in, even by a tiny bit, there is going to be a conflict between the sum of the constraints (General to top, height of General, General to bottom) and the cell height (175), and the runtime is going to have to throw away some of your constraints. That seems to be what is happening. You should see a notice in the Console about this.

Anyway, just delete the constraint between the General label and the bottom of the cell and things should be much better. (You might also want to delete the constraint between the General label and right side of the cell.)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Removing that function will still cause the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the constraints you added to label. because the constraint has a priority property, and releationship with two other items.
like this:

[image]

so the fist thins i suggest, is you can check this, or give out more info about this constraint. 
and you can test that:

1. delete all constraints for General label
2. only add two constaint, one is label.leading = cell.leading with offset, one is label.top = cell.top with offset
3. check the result is correct.

---

A tips for me: if you don't know why is incorrect with some condition, you can delete all of them and  add one by one again. may be you will find the mistake.